# siunitx 3 "quotient-mode" has been removed in this release

Tags: siunitx

With the upgrade to version 3.0.0 of siunitx it is no longer possible to use fractions in units.

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    quotient-mode = fraction,
}
\begin{document}
\num{7 / 2}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

```
[...]

Package siunitx Warning: Option "quotient-mode" has been removed in this
(siunitx)                release.

[...]

! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '7 / 2'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.7 \num{7 / 2}
```

In version 2 it would generate a document with a fraction 7 / 2.

The documentation only gives the following hint, but I am not sure how to interpret it.

> - Quotients of numbers are only supported as literals;

What can I do to obtain the old behaviour?
Should I skip siunitx entirely and just write `$\frac{7}{2}$`?
This would ignore any siunitx setting, but for all I know they were also ignored in previous versions for fractions.

Comment: Did you try parse-number=false?

Comment: In that case I get `! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '7 / 2'.`

Comment: `\num[parse-numbers=false]{7 / 2}`  works for me.

Comment: I tried `parse-numbers=false` (with plural), now it compiles, but it does not generate a fraction, just the three characters "7/2" (seven, slash, two).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a by-design change, and one reason for the major version step.  Fractions really do not fit in with the entire idea of parsing numbers into parts, and I've tried hard to tighten up the details here. You'll need

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[parse-numbers = false]{\frac{7}{2}}
\end{document}
```

to use a fraction now.

Comment: I agree with the design-choice, but the manual could have required a **slightly more detailed** chanegelog/deprecation info with conversion info...

Comment: What about “fractions” inputed as 7÷2? How is that semantically very different from 7×2? Also, is there a way for `\numproduct{7×2}` to work like it use to do before with `input-product = ×`?

Comment: And finally, how do I make something like `\numlist{1.2×3;3.4×2.15;0.200×1.40;44÷1.1}` work without resorting to `parse-numbers = false`?

Comment: (I can open new questions for each if you prefer, but I thought they are all related to the switch to numproduct)

Comment: @Archange The semantics for `\numproduct` are really for the case `2m x 2m` for say a piece of wood: this is not the same as saying the surface area is `4m^2`, and certainly isn't like `2m / 2m`.

Comment: @JosephWright But then those are `\qtyproduct`. And even then I see reasons for allowing such cases, for instances when one want to produce exact fraction of a quantity (think about e.g. the Debye definition or defining one arcmin in degrees). Is that really unreasonable to expect `7÷2` to work (by printing exactly that, not some math fraction)? And what about upgrading `input-product = ×` to 3.x?

Comment: When I use `\num[parse-numbers = false]{\frac{7}{2}}` in `equation` environment, nothing is printed.  Does this means that fractions can no longer be used in siunitx?  OK, for dimensionless quantities I could stop using `siunitx` at all, I am not sure what to do with others...

Comment: @Pygmalion Without an example I can't help: this should print just fine

Comment: I am sorry, it suddenly started to work for both`\num` and `\qty`.  Strange!