# \xfrac or \nicefrac in siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, xfrac, nicefrac

Is there a way of presenting 1/2 kg using `siunitx` by displaying the number fraction in `\xfrac` or `\nicefrac`? `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{1/2}{\kg}` command DOES NOT do it!

Comment: Did you give `\qty[parse-numbers=false]{\nicefrac{1}{2}}{\kg}` a try?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598236/263192

Comment: @Mirco it worked. Thank you.